# Tell a Task to wait until Timer has stopped

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer, task-parallel-library

**Explanation & Background:**
Sorry if this question sucks, but I am trying to wrap my head around Tasks. I currently have a set of classes that will take a control into their constructors, and allow for me to automate user interaction (typing into textbox, clicking button, etc.).

An example of one of these is my class called `TextboxTester`. Here is a snippet of how I bring in the textbox:

```
public class TextboxTester
{
    private int _currentTextLength = 0;
    private string _text;
    private TextBox _textBox;
    private Timer timer;

    #region Constructor
    public TextboxTester(TextBox TextBox)
    {
        _textBox = TextBox;
    }
    #endregion
```

I want to be able to chain actions(tasks) together in order - one after another so I can automate a series of user input events. I read up and found out about TPL tasks, and decided to give it a spin.

I created my `TextboxTester` class and my `ButtonTester` class, and passed in the controls. I want to be able to type into the textbox, and then click the button - so I call this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => txtTester.WriteText("Hello World")).Wait();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => btnTester.Click(1));
```

From my knowledge of the Task.Factory calls, this is what I want to do - perform the first action, wait until it is done - and then perform the next. The problem is that `TextboxTester.WriteText()` uses a timer to emulate typing into a `TextBox` (1 character per second):

```
public void WriteText(string Text)
    {
        if (timer == null)
        {
            State.Working = true;
            timer = new Timer();

            try
            {
                _text = Text;
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_ElapsedWrite);
                timer.Interval = 1000;
                timer.Enabled = true;
                timer.Start();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("WriteText timer could not be started.");
            }
        }
    }
void timer_ElapsedWrite(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _textBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            TextBoxAutomationPeer peer = new TextBoxAutomationPeer(_textBox);
            IValueProvider valueProvider = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Value) as IValueProvider;
            valueProvider.SetValue(_text.Substring(0, _currentTextLength));

            if (_currentTextLength == _text.Length)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                State.Working = false;
                timer = null;
                return;
            }

            _currentTextLength++;

        }));
    }
```

**The `_textBox.Dispatcher` call in the elapsed event was to prevent a "thread already owns this object" message that was occurring.

**Finally the problem:** The Task.Factory.StartNew() call does not seem to take into account the time_elapsed event that is still occurring. I want to be able to finish out the events before the Task considers "WriteText" is complete.

**and Question:**
Is there a way to tell a task to be able to take these types of things into account? Am I not understanding Tasks?

***EDIT -*** I am using 3.5 and a 3.5 implementation of TPL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are getting no benefits from using tasks. Making `WriteText` an async method can make things much easier:

```
public async Task WriteText(string text)
{
    TextBoxAutomationPeer peer = new TextBoxAutomationPeer(_textBox);
    IValueProvider valueProvider = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Value) as IValueProvider;
    for(int i = 1; i < text.Length; ++i)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // no need for timer
        valueProvider.SetValue(text.Substring(0, i));
    }
}
```

So you can write

```
async void TestMethod()
{
   await txtTester.WriteText("Hello World"));
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => btnTester.Click(1)); // probably sould be refactored too
}
```

**Edit**

Version without async/await with minimal changes to existing code:

```
public class TextboxTester
{
    /* unchanged code */

    // unfortunately, there is no non-generic version of this class
    // basically it allows us to 'manually' complete Task
    private TaskCompletionSource<object> _tcs;

    public Task WriteText(string Text)
    {
        if (timer == null)
        {
            _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            /* unchanged code */
        }
        return _tcs.Task; // return task which tracks work completion
    }

    /* unchanged code */
            if (_currentTextLength == _text.Length)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                State.Working = false;
                timer = null;
                _tcs.TrySetResult(null); // notify completion
                return;
            }
    /* unchanged code */
}
```

Now you can write

```
// well, you could simply make this a blocking method instead
txtTester.WriteText("Hello World").Wait();
btnTester.Click(1);
```

or better

```
txtTester.WriteText("Hello World")
         .ContinueWith(t => btnTester.Click(1)); // does not block calling thread
```

Main idea is to design your async method in a way which allows reporting completion. There are 3 common patterns for that:

- Begin/End method pairs (`BeginWriteText`, which returns `IAsyncResult` and `EndWriteText`, which accepts `IAsyncResult`)
- Event which is invoked when work is completed (`public event EventHandler WriteTextCompleted`)
- Task-based approach (method returns `Task`)

These approaches are well described in [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957)

Comment: I should have specified that I am in a 3.5 project with a 3.5 reimplementation of TPL (Reactive Extensions).

Comment: Worked, Thank you! But blocks the UI thread because of that dispatcher. Going to have to figure that one out next! Thanks!